# Linux command to move file from desktop to phone on home network

Tags: linux, bash, networking, command-line, filesystems

I need to transfer a particular file from my Linux PC to Android phone using a Bash script. I have already exposed my phone filesystem to the PC. With this I can easily communicate between the two using nautilus and GS Connect on PC and KDE Connect on phone.
By the way my both devices are on same home network.
Please Help!

Comment: If you enable USB debugging you can transfer using `adb push` and `adb pull`.

Comment: MTP is not recommended for cmd line (because it doesn't refresh changes). native [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) is more stable and works even wireless via [TCP/IP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry)

Comment: [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) or [adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) for more advanced usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution using sftp.
I have used the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash
#Capture and share screenshot to my phone
gnome-screenshot
cd /home/prm/Pictures
FILE="$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)" #To get the last created file
echo $FILE
sftp sftp://192.168.1.3:1761/primary/DCIM/Screenshots <<EOF
put "$FILE"
bye
EOF
```

Comment: you may mention in your answer how do you run ftp server on android (afaik it isn't possible without root access?)